# How can I read csv files from the link stored in django model within views file?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, folium

I am creating a map with Folium, Django and Pandas. I created a django model where I store my csv file's url. I want to read csv files from there dynamically so that I can use different data dynamically. How can I do that? I used a url of a csv file. I want to make it dynamic so that I can fetch one from models directly. Here is my code. I will be very grateful for your assistance.

```
def mapview(request, map_pk):
srlist = Map.objects.filter(pk=map_pk)
bd = pd.read_csv("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IohEgJi8ajDoHyPF315vi13F3m0vDtbl7DzmSmtUHpA/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(bd)
lat = df[['lat']]
lng = df[['lng']]
m = folium.Map(title='Bangladesh', location=[23.7805733, 90.2792399], zoom_start=7)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    folium.Marker(location=[row['lat'], row['lng']]).add_to(m)
m = m._repr_html_()
context = {

 'm':m,
 'bd':bd,
 'lat': lat,
 'lng': lng,
 'srlist':srlist,
 'df':df,

}

return render(request, 'map/mapview.html', context)
```

Comment: What is error are you getting in above code. Please explain your in a bit clear language.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There is no error. I just want to know how can I get the url directly from Django Models and place it into pd.read_csv("...") dynamically. Currently I am not able to use the urls stored in my django model.

Comment: In order to use urls from your database follow this syntax: ```field_name.url```

Comment: Where should I use it? Can you elaborate it even more?

Comment: Post to your ```Map``` model so that i can talk specifically.

Comment: Thanks for your effort to help me. I just needed to create a loop function and it worked.